# How to fill in the DataGridTextColumn through part of the aggregated object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, aggregation

I want to fill in the field DataGridTextColumn through part of the aggregated object.
I want to binding only a field Nazwa (not whole object Wynik) of the class Rezultat to the following DataGridTextColumn. 
How I can do this ?

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Rezultat}" Header="Rezultat"/>
```

C#:

```
public class Rezultat
{
    public int IdWyniku { get; set; }
    public int IdZdarzenia { get; set; }
    public int IdUżytkownika { get; set; }
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }

    public Rezultat() { }

    public Rezultat(int IdZdarzenia, int IdUżytkownika, string Nazwa, int IdWyniku=0)
    {
        this.IdZdarzenia = IdZdarzenia;
        this.IdUżytkownika = IdUżytkownika;
        this.Nazwa = Nazwa;
        this.IdWyniku = IdWyniku;
    }
}

public class Zdarzenie
{
    public Rezultat Wynik { get; set; }
}
```

C# (piece of code from another class):

```
this.ListaKuponów[0].ListaZdarzeń.Add(new Zdarzenie()
{                       
    Wynik = new Rezultat(Convert.ToInt32(napis.ItemArray.GetValue(7)), this.IdRejestracji, wynik, idwyniku),  
});
```

Comment: You bind against a **property/path named** *Rezultat*, but in your example code above i cannot see this property being declared anywhere. (a class is not a property or path!) I suppose the binding works against DataContext -- what kind of object have you bound/assigned to DataContext?

Comment: The fastest, most expedient way to do this is to keep the binding like it is and overload the ToString() method of the Rezultat class, and return the string representation of whatever you want.  If the data context has been set correctly, the DataGridTextColumn will know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out earlier in the comments, you haven't shown us the property you are binding.

Assuming you implemented property `Result` of type `Rezultat` you'd need to bind to Nazwa in the markup as follows:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Result.Nazwa}" Header="Rezultat"/>
```

**Note:** If you haven't got implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on this class, you won't receive any updates if the field changes. You'd need to create either an extra ViewModel or implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your model. (Assuming that you are actually using the MVVM pattern)